# display: table-cell, not working on responsive

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to markup an easy 4 column grid using `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` but adapting as good as possible in responsive design?

Example, I have a 4 columns with 2 rows on desktop version (This is working perfectly, I'm showing products btw) but when I want to have 2 column on table version if I add `width:50%;` to the columns this seems not to be working.

I want to know if there is a better practice using this `display` or if I'm missing something or what method do you guys suggest me to implement I would not prefer `float` but you guys are the ninjas here so feel free to teach me some advices.

Here's my markup and my CSS:

HTML:

```
<section class="products">
    <div class="products__row">
        <article class="products__item">
            <div class="products__item--thumbnail">
                <img src="img/products/thumbnail-1.jpg" alt="thumbnail-img">
            </div>
            <h2 class="products__item--title">Jabones Naturales</h2>
            <p class="products__item--info">Jabones antioxidantes a base de avena, mandarina y té verde.</p>
            <h3 class="products__item--price">60.00</h3>
            <span class="fa fa-search products__item-cart"></span>
        </article>
     </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.products {
    border-spacing: 16px;
    display: table;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    caption-side: top;
}
    .products__row {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .products__item {
        display: table-cell;
        width: 25%;
        padding-left: 1rem;
        padding-right: 1rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        outline: 1px dashed #ccc;
        outline-offset: -16px;
    }
        @media all and (max-width: 960px) {
            .products__item {
                background-color: blue;
                width: 50%;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT.**

Here's a JS Fiddle with the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/3r2mcv0p/

Comment: You have `table-cell` elements nested in each other, and you're applying that to a variety of element types. You'd do better to follow the standard `table > table-row > table-cell` protocol and use divs for each. Put your paragraphs, headings, etc. inside those containers.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're looking to do this with table layouts instead of `inline-block` elements? Or better yet, if your browser support needs are modern, using flexbox?

Comment: But I'm following that format, I have a container with display:table; and products__item has a display:table-cell and inside those I have paragraphs, heading, etc, I don't know where's the problem.